# Unable to reach webserver behind firewall from one device but not the other

Tags: routing

I have encountered 2 very strange issues with my network at home (setup as below).  Really appreciate if anyone can give any insights.

**Issue 1**
I can access the web page from my iPhone by launching Safari and typing in 192.168.60.4.  However when I try to do the same on my PC, it wouldn't work.  In both cases I can see on the XTM21's Traffic Monitor that it has "Allow" the traffic through from both the iPhone and PC to the Webserver.

**Issue 2**
If I ping the Webserver from my iPhone, every time I can get a response.  However if I ping the Webserver from my PC, I'll get "Request timed out".  Now the interesting bit is if I then ping 192.168.20.22 (the XTM21) first, I can then ping the Webserver and get a valid response.  This will remain for a while and the problem repeat itself again.

On the Buffalo Router, I have gone to Internet/LAN -> Route and added the following:
Destination Address:  192.168.60.0/24
Subnet Mask:  255.255.255.0
Gateway:  192.168.20.22
Metric:  1 (this is defined as maximum number of routers which may be traversed before reaching the destination)

Rather than adding this route on the Buffalo Router, can I advertise the Webserver's details or any other device in the 192.168.60.0/24 network to the 192.168.20.0/24 network?  I haven't and don't know how to do this and am not sure whether this is the reason why I'm experiencing the issues above.  Even then, not sure why in both cases it works for my iPhone but not my PC.

```
Internet -> Buffalo Router -> 192.168.20.1/24
                           -> iPhone (192.168.20.6)
                           -> PC (192.168.20.15)
                           -> Watchguard XTM21 (192.168.20.22) -> 192.168.60.1/24  
                                                               -> Webserver (192.168.60.4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, by the sounds of your statement, you are only getting 1 device through the firewall trunk.

What you could try is configuring the PC to be permitted all the time on the DMZ firewall. As you said, if it gets a connection via ping, it will connect for a duration. Maybe you could have a look to see if the connection is not getting reset on the XTM21. As it seems a little bit bizarre that the iPhone can get in, but not the PC. The problem resides in your Firewall setup, your network is fine and your Router is routing between subnets as can be seen from the iPhone connection (192.168.20.x -> 192.168.60.x) via the firewall.

Hint: Check your connection limits.

Comment: Hi, thanks for looking at this.  Can you elborate what you meant by "What you could try is configuring the PC to be permitted all the time on the DMZ firewall."?  I only have a simple setup with 2 subnets on either side of the XTM21 and no DMZ.  Also, can you give me some pointers on how I can do "Maybe you could have a look to see if the connection is not getting reset on the XTM21."?  In terms of the connection limits, the Policy on the XTM21 that permits 192.168.20.0/24 to 192.168.60.0/24 has Connection Rate = No Limit.